# Unpermitted parameters error for Carrierwave in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

Ok, really stuck here.  Have read through all documentation and SO but can't figure out what's going on.  Simple case of allowing a User to update their profile by uploading a file using Carrierwave.  My log keeps showing an

```
Unpermitted parameters: avatar
```

error.

My view:

```
<%= form_for current_user, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
 <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
 <%= f.submit "Update Profile", remote: true, class: "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

my controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController  

  def update
    current_user.update_attributes(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render 'show'}
      format.js {}
    end
  end

  def user_params
    params.fetch(:user, {}).permit(:id, :email, :username, :password, :password_hash, :avatar, projects_attributes: [:id, :user_id, :name])
  end
end
```

my model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end
```

have not touched the uploader file

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

Seems pretty straightforward, why am I getting this error?

UPDATE:  Server Log:

```
Started PATCH "/users/91" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-03 11:38:22 -0700
Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+cLF9iPcZSL3Lc87o7/gPZjwgc9ySr7dOKmm6Yxhbno=", "user"=>{"username"=>"s+ Index", "avatar_attributes"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f81db4060c8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/xl/wpdby5jn59q7hy9w0v2nv8xc0000gn/T/RackMultipart20140403-3890-127m17g>, @original_filename="cover.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar_attributes]\"; filename=\"cover.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Update Profile", "id"=>"91"}
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 91]]
Unpermitted parameters: avatar
```

Comment: Can you share the complete server log in the question. It would help in debugging.

Comment: Kirti, updated above, thank you.

Comment: Kirti, never mind, it's working.

Comment: No problem. If your issue is resolved then you can post an answer.

Comment: what was the solution????

Comment: did you find the problem ?

Comment: I found the problem in a (mostly) unrelated post: `rake tmp:clear`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23469084/ruby-on-rails-no-implicit-conversion-of-array-into-string-devise

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem,

I had a problem because I had fallowed documentation like so:

```
<%= f.file_field :avatar, multiple: true %>
```

Changed it to:

```
<%= form_for @user,  multiple: true do |f| %>
```

in controller:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:avatar,...)
```